# Do you "supplement" your income?

Tags: word-choice

Say you're a teacher and for the summer you need a job... to "supplement" your income? I'm helping a friend with her résumé (under reason for applying) and any help would be appreciated.

**Definition of supplement: Add an extra element or amount to.**

Doesn't seem right, so I'm just making sure.

Comment: I don't think she is supplementing her _husband's_ income but rather the _family_ income.  The husband can get a job on the side to supplement _his_ income or could work extra hours to supplement his income, but the wife does not supplement _his_ income unless she is paying _him_.  But the way, do be careful about writing things such as "your a teacher" which will pass a spell-checker but are jarring to read.

Comment: 'Supplement' is generally going to either be a noun ("The vitamin is a supplement to an already healthy diet") or it can be a verb ("She is looking for additional income to supplement her current income").

Answer (score 2):

I've used the phrase myself before and heard it dozens of times in all kinds of contexts. It is correct, it is in common usage, and no one is going to think it sounds funny.

However, from a resume perspective, please don't make supplementary income the focus of "reason for applying." Nobody who is looking to hire wants to read that as the #1 reason, even if it's true.

Comment: Great point. OP could try to explain the intended use for the monies from a goal-oriented perspective, but it would still be some muddy water to tread.

Answer (score 2):

Do I supplement my income? Whenever possible.

> **supplement**, *tr. v.* : to fill up or supply by additions : add something to : fill the deficiencies of : as
>   **a** : to serve as a supplement for {the frontiersman depended for game to supplement his meager larder -- R.A.Billington}
>
> **b** : to supply a supplement for {he signed mutual defense treaties ... and supplemented many with favorable commercial agreements --
>   R.E.Lee}

Either sense (*a* or *b*) would apply to the entry on your friend's résumé.